# lake shore, sea coast, river side

Tags: vocabulaire, géographie

What do you call these three things in French?

lake shore, sea coast, river side

Here are my suggestions:

- lake shore = rive du lac
- sea coast = côte de la mer, côte
- river side = côté rivière

Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

We do not say *côté rivière* or *côte de la mer* although *côte méditerranéenne* is fine.
Here are some possible terms:

- lake shore = *rive, rives du lac, berge, bord de lac*
- sea coast = *rivage, côte, littoral, bord de mer, grève*<sup>1</sup>
- river side = *rive (e.g. rive droite, rive gauche), berge, bord (bords de Marne), grève*<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> *Grève* is literary.

Comment: _Berge_ me paraît convenir aussi pour un lac. En fait je ne fais pas de distinction entre un lac ou un étang et une rivière ou un fleuve.

Comment: @mouviciel Oui, berge peut aussi s'appliquer à un lac. Réponse mise à jour, merci !